# AUTOCOMPLETE SUGGESTIONS APPEARS ON TOP OF TEXT BOX -WINDOWS PHONE

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, autocomplete, windows-phone

I am using auto complete textbox from windows phone toolkit.I need the list of suggestions below my textbox but it shows up above the text box .How do I make the suggestions appear below the text box..Here is my XAML.

```
<Grid Margin="0,336,0,189" x:Name="editrow" Visibility="Visible">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220" ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="newname" FilterMode="StartsWith"  IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" Foreground="White" Background="#53000000" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsDropDownOpen="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
                    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="Gray" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="rowquantity" Foreground="White" Background="#53000000" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" InputScope="Number"></TextBox>
                <toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="0" x:Name="units" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" Background="#53000000" Grid.Column="2" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Margin="12,5,0,14" >
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 0">

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                 FontSize="32" LineHeight="1"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
                <Button Content="Add" BorderBrush="#53000000" Foreground="#53000000" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="74" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,0,3,0" Width="158"/>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the popup is determined based on the available size. If there's more space above the `AutoCompleteTextBox`, it will pop up. You can see this in the [`popuphelper.cs`](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/AutoCompleteBox/PopupHelper.cs) source file where the code arranges the popup.

There really isn't an option to override the behavior.