# How to change the postion of result to down in autocomplete box for windows phone8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, autocompletebox

I'm developing wp 8 application.

I'm using autocomplete box. autocomplete box value is bind form json web service.

Value bind correctly but the result show in top of autocomplete box. i need it display below the autocomplete box.

My XAML code for autocomplete box

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox 
            x:Name="Autocbox" 
            FilterMode="StartsWith" 
            ValueMemberBinding="{Binding cityname}" 
            SelectionChanged="Autocbox_SelectionChanged"
            Height="100">

            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding cityname}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
    </Grid>
```

OutPut:- [Now output come like this]

[image]

**But I Need Output come like this**

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Launch blend and look itemContainerStyle and remove margin on listboxitem.

Comment: @MatDev8 I'm new Wp8 development. I check In itemcontainerstyle  But there is no option for remove margin

Comment: Yeah ok, i understand now but it's not really firendly used and maybe your app can't pass microsoft certification. Dropdownlist will passed over the keyboard and i think it's not really a good solution.

Comment: How to Solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my problem.From below stack overflow link
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752544/autocomplete-suggestions-appears-on-top-of-text-box-windows-phone)

I changed my Grid layout code Into

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and my content panel grid margin

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
```

The main reason for the popup up problem is due to more space above the AutoCompleteTextBox

I don't think it's correct way to solve this problem.

But now my design work correctly.

My Output :-

[image]